# Pig Round Decimal to Two Places

Tags: apache-pig

Any ideas on how I Can Round a Float data type to 2 decimal places in Apache Pig?

For example:

```
  test = FOREACH (JOIN Load by (Op1, Op2), Load2 by (Op3,Op4)) GENERATE 
  Load2::Number2 *Load::Number1 as Output
```

The fields Number1 and Number2 are floats.My current calculations give me 5 to 6 decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 B = FOREACH A GENERATE (((A.myfloat1 * A.myfloat2)*100f)ROUND)/100f AS myfloat3
```

Comment: Tried that. Looks like ti does not like the parenthesis.                                                                                                                            ERROR 1200: <line 1, column 212>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '('

Comment: Alright, I have edited my example to illustrate how to round a float to 2 decimal places.