# Pig round the decimal with 8 places

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to know,how to round the double value with eight decimal places in PIG.I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538504/pig-round-decimal-to-two-places) but it is not helping me. Any ideas

Comment: You'll have the most fine-grained control writing a UDF. You could use this as a starting point: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/ROUND.java

Comment: Thx for suggestion. I don't want to use the UDF on the other hand i want to achieve this in Pig Latin. And i even implemented in pig code for the same. Code: (ROUND((1205.67534337)*100000000f))/100000000f, it is working fine for rounding the digits upto 3-4 decimal points and it is not working correctly for 8 decimals. Can you suggest! Where we went wrong or any other way to achive "rounding up any digits to 8 decimal points".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ROUND(1205.6753433723*100000000.0)/100000000.0;`

`100000000f` is a Float Constant and `100000000.0` is a Double Constant;

Answer (score 2):

ROUND_TO(0.9876543, 3) is 0.988;

Please have a look at the below URL:-
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/ROUND_TO.html

Comment: This doesn't work. See my error
`ERROR 1070: Could not resolve ROUND_TO using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]`